# React event handling for complex hierarchy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started a game project in ReactJS as a way to learn the framework and I'm stuck in a problem I have.

I am using `react-hexgrid` as my core component, it's based on hexagons. I have six `<HexTile/>` pieces consisting of two `<Hexagon/>` each and a `<GameLayout/>` board where I can drag&drop them.

The `<HexTile/>` has to be placed completely on the `<GameLayout/>`, I achieve this dropping an `<Hexagon/>` each time with a `first` variable indicating that's the first hex dropped. The problem is that I need the remaining `<HexTile/>`s to be blocked while the move is completed. I want to put the six `<HexTile/>` inside a `<TileList/>` but because the drag events listeners are binded to the `<Hexagon/>` components, I don't know how to tell the `<TileList/>` that a move is being done so it disables the other `<HexTile/>`s.

How can I make the `<TileList/>` listen the `<HexTile/>` drag events? `<HexTile/>` is based on `<TilesLayout/>` component here (the game itself takes this example as base):  https://github.com/Hellenic/react-hexgrid/tree/master/examples/drag-and-drop

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use Redux (react-redux) to handle events as soon as you have a situation that is not trivial to solve with props and state. Then you don't need to think about components hierarchy anymore when dealing with events. The more complex your application, the more you will like using Redux.

Comment: Can you add state to your `TileList` that listens to that drag event? Something like `isTileMoving` and pass a handler which sets that state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
class TileList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { isTileMoving: false }

    this.onDragStart = this.onDragStart.bind(this)
    this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this)
  }

  onDragStart(evt, source) {
    this.setState({ isTileMoving: true })
  }

  onDragEnd(evt, source) {
    this.setState({ isTileMoving: false })
  }

  // ... Rest of your things

  render() {
    <div>
      <Hexagon onDragStart={this.onDragStart} onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd} />
      <Hexagon onDragStart={this.onDragStart} onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd} />
      <Hexagon onDragStart={this.onDragStart} onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd} />
      <Hexagon onDragStart={this.onDragStart} onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd} />
    </div>
}
```

And in your `Hexagon`

```
class Hexagon extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = // Hexagon state
  }

  onDragStart(evt, source) {
    this.props.onDragStart(evt, source)
    // Rest of your drag
  }

  onDragEnd(evt, source) {
    this.props.onDragEnd(evt, source)
    // Rest of dragEnd
  }

  // ... Rest of your things

  render() {
    //whatever your render is
  }
}
```